# Lipschitz-continuity of a particular function

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions

I have the following question. Let $ g_1,\ldots,g_k: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be Lipschitz continuous (with respective constants $ L_1,\ldots,L_k>0 $). How can I proove the Lipschitz-continuity of the function
$ h(x):=\left(\sum_{i=1}^k |g_i(x)|^d\right)^{\frac{1}{d}} $ for $ d>1$?

I don't know how to proceed here in order to use the Lipschitz condition for the functions $ g_i $:
$ |h(x)-h(y)|=\left|\left(\sum_{i=1}^k |g_i(x)|^d\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}-\left(\sum_{i=1}^k |g_i(y)|^d\right)^{\frac{1}{d}} \right| $

Comment: Are you aware of $p$-norms?  Of the [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality)?

Comment: Hello, of course I am aware of the Minkowski inequality. Unfortunately, I did not manage to apply it here (since I tried to merge the two sums somehow which was not successfull). But now, I saw the trick $g_i(x)=g_i(x)-g_i(y)+g_i(y) $. Afterwards, the Minkowski inequality can be applied and the new Lipschitz constant should result to $ \left( \sum_{i=1}^k L_i^d\right)^{\frac{1}{d}} $, right?

Comment: That's right.  In particular, we have
$$
\left|\left(\sum_{i=1}^k |g_i(x)|^d\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}-\left(\sum_{i=1}^k |g_i(y)|^d\right)^{\frac{1}{d}} \right| \leq
\left(\sum_{i=1}^k |g_i(x) - g_i(y)|^d\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}
$$
By the triangle inequality

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Then this problem is solved!

Comment: great! If you want, you can write up an answer and accept it to resolve this question post

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of the previous comments I was able to find the answer. As mentioned there, the trick $ g(x)=g(x)-g(y)+g(y) $ and the triangle inequality lead to the following:
$ |h(x)-h(y)|=\left|\left(\sum_{i=1}^k |g_i(x)|^d\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}-\left(\sum_{i=1}^k |g_i(y)|^d\right)^{\frac{1}{d}} \right| \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^k |g_i(x) - g_i(y)|^d\right)^{\frac{1}{d}} \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^k L_i|x-y|^d\right)^{\frac{1}{d}} = \left( \sum_{i=1}^k L_i^d\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}\cdot |x-y|$.